# If a function has slowly varying amplitude and phase what is the bandwidth of the amplitude and phase individually?

Tags: filters, modulation, algorithms, signal-detection

I am dealing with time histories that are narrow band with slowly varying amplitude and phase. I wish to extract the amplitude and phase but there is noise on the time history. An example of the type of time history I am dealing with is as follows:

[image: Time history]

This is a decaying oscillation but does not have an exponential decay. A short part of the time history shows that there is noise on the decaying amplitude:

[image: Expanded part of time history]

The modulus of the Fourier transform of the time history shows a clear peak:

[image: Spectrum of time history]

I have drawn lines at $f_1$ and $f_2$ that contain the bandwidth of the time history I am interested in. However, there is noise at a frequency of about 230 Hz that spoils the data.

If I extract the amplitude and frequency the noise can be clearly seen.

[image: Amplitude]

[image: Frequency]

I wish to remove the nose from the amplitude and frequency time histories I have estimated. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) gives many examples of smoothing methods such as low pass filter, Savitzky-Golay and moving average. Each of these methods requires a knowledge of the bandwidth of the signal being smoothed. My question is: what is this bandwidth?

My intuition is that the bandwidth is equal to 0 to $f_2-f_1%$ Hz or a smoothing time interval of $\frac{1}{f_2-f_1}%$. Is this correct? Is there a rigorous proof of this or are there references you can point me towards?

I think the problem is different to finding the amplitude of an amplitude modulated frequency because my frequency is also time varying.

Thanks for any help.